# client error (400) using gsheet2tbl to get Google Sheet data

Tags: r, google-sheets

Since Rcurl no longer works for importing data into R from Google Sheets, I have been using gsheet2tbl.

This has been working well but today I was trying to download from a recently created Google Sheet and I received the following error:

```
url2<-"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit?usp=sharing"

d <- gsheet2tbl(url2, sheetid = 0)

Error in parse.response(r, parser, encoding = encoding) : 
client error: (400) Bad Request
```

I double checked and everything is working just fine with my previously created Google Sheets.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks very much,

Matt

Comment: Since I can't install gsheet2tbl apparently, I'll have to ask. What is `ur12`?

Comment: I downloaded the the "sharing link" url from google sheets.  To protect my data here is the first part of the url

Comment: All you needed to say was the connection. Is it connecting to a folder then?

Comment: It's connecting to a Google Sheet that is in a folder in my Google Drive.  Sorry if my answer seems a bit naive.  I'm getting better in R but this is certainly beyond my skill set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new package for reading from Google sheets... https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

I find that it's fantastic for this sort of work. Give it a shot...

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/googlesheets")
# run this and it will ask for user authentication...
gs_ls()
gs_read(ws = "Your worksheet")
```

Comment: I tried to run it and I'm receiving the error:  
Skipping 1 packages not available: xml2
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD  \
  INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/53/np04m96n58dgzjccgr87kbm80000gn/T/RtmphM0LHQ/devtoolsa31b40a53eca/jennybc-googlesheets-c02b627'  \
  --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘googlesheets’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/googlesheets’

Comment: any quick thoughts? this package seems great - I would love to get it working

Comment: try installing xml2 from github first... `devtools::install_github("hadley/xml2")`

Comment: Now that I think about it... I think there was some dust up about xml2 on CRAN... so installing from github is probably advisable for now.

Comment: I just use the sheet name.

Comment: I think OP tried to install googlesheets exactly when xml2 fell off of CRAN briefly. Hopefully install and usage went fine once that dependency sorted out.